# how to merge two different CI application to become one application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have two codeigniter applications. One is for **Customer Management** and one is for **Lead Management**. I want to **merge** Lead Management application into Customer Management so I can access functionality of Lead Management application from Customer Management application.

But I'm not figure it out how can I do that. Means I have to make sub folder and copy all code/files from Lead Management into Customer Management application, just some files. But both application have different code.

https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/07/08/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter/

I go through above link, but here they explain how to create two applications using CI.

I don't no this is a write question or not but, any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're still running everything through the main applications folder, shouldn't be hard to access the functionality of one application in the other, no merging should need to be required really? the helpers/controllers/methods should be available to both... unless I am missing something?

Comment: I'm done two separate installation for both with different hosting, but I want single installation on my server.

Comment: Ah I see, are you using the same database type for both (MySQL/Postgres/etc?). are there any conflicting named files in the models / views / controllers? BTW the post you have quoted is very, very, very old...

Comment: yes, I'm using MySQL DB. and there are no any conflicting name in both apps. I'm google it for last two days, I'm just gate that post, but not exact answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a good deal of manual labor and merging your codebase, then setting up the databases on your single server... If you want to merge those together I suggest prefixing the tables when you move them over unless there are no conflicts which is probably unlikely.

From there you'll need to tailor your CI setup to suit. There is no "easy way" to do this and will all be manual.